# reorganize mail folders (not in V4 on Sierra)

Tags: mail.app, gmail, folders, imap

A while ago, after filling my MacBookPro disk, I (stupidly!) moved my Mail (all IMAP or Gmail) folders to an external disk (using `Terminal`). After cleaning up my disk, I did

> Mailbox > Rebuild

on each of my Mail folders, but on my work IMAP account my files has mostly disappeared, so I had to recover them from a backup performed by the IT dept. at work. However, several problems arose:

1. the folders are no longer in `~/Library/Mail/V4` (Sierra)
2. the Message List is often incomplete (but using Spotlight helps locate the missing messages)
3. the Rules and Signatures have disappeared.

What should I do?

1. Copy the mailbox contents from another Mac (desktop, High Sierra)? What precise files (and Preference files) should I copy?
2. Upgrade my laptop MacOS to Mojave (hoping for the Mail folders to magically appear in `~/Library/Mail/V5`)?

Comment: If all the mails appear on the web interface, why not remove and add back the accounts in system Preferences ? and I suppose V6 is for Mojave. V5 is High Sierra.

Comment: I just solved my problem by 1) turning off all Internet accounts (keeping them on other iCloud machines), 2) Updating to Mojave, 3) the following https://appletoolbox.com/mail-not-working-after-macos-mojave-upgrade-how-to-fix/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my problem by:

1. turning off all Internet accounts (keeping them on other iCloud machines)
2. updating to Mojave
3. following the steps in https://appletoolbox.com/mail-not-working-after-macos-mojave-upgrade-how-to-fix/, which basically deletes several Mail-related files in `~/Library/Containers` and `~/Library/Mail`.

This allowed me to recover my mailboxes and also recover a lost synchronization in Notes between my Mac and iPhone.